# David Williams "Probability with Martingales" : Proof of Jensen inequality question

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

The proof is as follows:
[image]

My question: do we need to prove that $E(X) \in G$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X\in G$ almost surely, then $\mu\in G$ holds.
In your given proof G is an open interval, let's say $G = (a,b)$.

Then $X\in G$ ensure $a < X < b$ and so $a < \mu < b$ what means $\mu\in G$

Comment: But why is it obvious that a<X<b  implies  a< μ=E(X) < b ?

Comment: Use properties of expectation. From $a < X$ it follows $a = E[a] < E[X] = \mu$

Comment: ah yes we can use the Markov inequality to prove this : $E(Z) \ge c P(Z \ge c)$ with $Z=X-a \in mF+$ and c=0